# Async RenderAction

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, async-await, partial-views

I have a layout that calls several `@Html.RenderAction` in the layout

eg

```
@{ Html.RenderAction("TopPane", "Controller"); }
<div class="content-pane">
    @RenderBody()
</div>
@{ Html.RenderAction("BottomPane", "Controller"); }
```

Sometime the top pane can take a bit of time to render. Is it possible to make the render action async, eg

```
public class PartialAsyncController : AsyncController
{
    private long dt;
    public PartialAsyncController()
    {
        dt = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
    }

    public async Task<PartialViewResult> TopPane()
    {
        return PartialView(dt);
    }

    public async Task<PartialViewResult> BottomPane()
    {
        return PartialView(dt);
    }

}
```

I'd like to avoid using the ajax approach to rendering the top and bottom pane because they share expensive content that is scoped to once per request

Comment: What do you mean 'Sometime the top pane can take a bit of time to render.'?Is there some operation in `TopPane()` that will cost long time or just the render of partialview will take long time?

Comment: The query to generate the data in the top pane can take some time.

Comment: This is not what async returning controller methods are for. Execution does not continue until the task they return has completed.